# Not able to get proper data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, spring-boot, react-hooks, material-ui

I am creating an application using Springboot and ReactJS. In the client side I am entering the data through form using POST method. I am entering the proper values, But in response it is showing NULL values.

I checked from Postman also, there also it is showing same null response for some of the fields.

[image]

[image]

```
import React, {useState} from "react";
import {Card, Typography, CardContent, Button} from "@mui/material";
import Box from '@mui/material/Box';
import TextField from '@mui/material/TextField';
import Paper from '@mui/material/Paper';
import Grid from '@mui/material/Grid';
import axios from "axios";
import base_url from "../Api/BootApi";

const AddVehicles = () => {
    
const [vehicle,setVehicle] = useState({});

const handleForm=(e)=>{
console.log(vehicle);
postData(vehicle);
e.preventDefault();
}

const postData = (data) => {
axios.post(`${base_url}/vehicles`, data).then(
    (response) => {
        console.log(response)
        console.log("success")
    },(error)=>{
        console.log(error)
    }
)
}

    return (
        
       <>
       <Typography gutterBottom variant="h4" align="center">
           Add Vehicles
       </Typography>
        <Card variant="elevation" elevation={7} sx = {{maxWidth:450, margin: "0 auto", padding:"20px 5px"}}>
            <CardContent>
                <form onSubmit={handleForm}>
                <Typography gutterBottom varient="h5">
                    Add your vehicles details...
                </Typography>
            <Grid container spacing = {1}>
            
      <Grid item xs ={12} sm={4} >
      <TextField required type = "number" label="Vehicle ID" variant="outlined" placeholder=" eg. 1003" fullWidth id="id" onChange={(e)=>{
          setVehicle({...vehicle, id:e.target.value})
      }}/>
      </Grid>

      <Grid item xs ={12} sm={4} >
      <TextField  required type = "number" label="Vehicle REG" variant="outlined" placeholder="eg. 6123" fullWidth id="REG" onChange={(e)=>{
          setVehicle({...vehicle, REG:e.target.value})
      }}/>
      </Grid>

      <Grid item xs ={12} sm={4} >
      <TextField required type = "number" label="Vehicle VIN" variant="outlined" placeholder="eg. 9009" fullWidth id="VIN" onChange={(e)=>{
          setVehicle({...vehicle, VIN:e.target.value})
      }}/>
     </Grid>

      <Grid item xs ={12}  >
      <TextField required label="Maker" variant="outlined" placeholder="eg TATA" fullWidth id="maker" onChange={(e)=>{
          setVehicle({...vehicle, maker:e.target.value})
      }}/>
      </Grid>

      <Grid item xs ={12}  >
      <TextField required label="Model" variant="outlined" placeholder="eg NEXON" fullWidth id="model" onChange={(e)=>{
          setVehicle({...vehicle, model:e.target.value})
      }}/>
      </Grid>

      <Grid item xs ={12}  >
      <TextField required label="Variant" variant="outlined" placeholder="eg Electric" fullWidth id="variant" onChange={(e)=>{
          setVehicle({...vehicle, variant:e.target.value})
      }}/>
      </Grid>

      <Button type = "submit" sx={{margin:"20px 0px"}}variant="contained" color ="primary" fullWidth>Submit Details</Button>
      
      </Grid>
      </form>
      </CardContent>
      </Card>
    
   
      
       
            </>
    )
}

export default AddVehicles;
```

Can someone please help me, why it is behaving like this and How could I solve this?

Edit 1: Backend code Service Class

```
package com.test.vehiclemanagement.service;

import com.test.vehiclemanagement.model.Vehicle;
import com.test.vehiclemanagement.repository.VehicleRepository;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

@Service
public class VehicleServiceImpl implements VehicleService{


    @Autowired
    private VehicleRepository vr;


    public VehicleServiceImpl(){



    }

    @Override
    public List<Vehicle> getVehicles() {

        return vr.findAll();
    }

    @Override
    public Vehicle getVehicle(long vehicleId){

        return vr.getOne(vehicleId);
    }

    @Override
    public Vehicle addVehicle(Vehicle vehicle){
           vr.save(vehicle);
          return vehicle;

    }

    @Override
    public Vehicle updateVehicle(Vehicle vehicle){
              vr.save(vehicle);
              return vehicle;
    }

    @Override
    public void deleteVehicle(long parseLong){
        Vehicle entity = vr.getOne(parseLong);
        vr.delete(entity);
    }
}
```

Vehicle class:

```
package com.test.vehiclemanagement.model;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity
public class Vehicle {

    @Id
    private long id;
    private String make;
    private String model;
    private String variant;
    private int VIN;
    private int REG;

    public Vehicle(long id, String make, String model, String variant, int VIN, int REG) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.make = make;
        this.model = model;
        this.variant = variant;
        this.VIN = VIN;
        this.REG = REG;
    }

    public Vehicle(){
        super();
    }

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getMake() {
        return make;
    }

    public void setMake(String make) {
        this.make = make;
    }

    public String getModel() {
        return model;
    }

    public void setModel(String model) {
        this.model = model;
    }

    public String getVariant() {
        return variant;
    }

    public void setVariant(String variant) {
        this.variant = variant;
    }

    public int getVIN() {
        return VIN;
    }

    public void setVIN(int VIN) {
        this.VIN = VIN;
    }

    public int getREG() {
        return REG;
    }

    public void setREG(int REG) {
        this.REG = REG;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Vehicle{" +
                "id=" + id +
                ", make='" + make + '\'' +
                ", model='" + model + '\'' +
                ", variant='" + variant + '\'' +
                ", VIN=" + VIN +
                ", REG=" + REG +
                '}';
    }
}
```

Comment: Can we see your backend code?

Comment: @Enfieldli I shared the Service Class for the same. Also while performing the POST method from Postman, It is working fine. But from client side I am getting the NULL values for some of my entities.

Comment: Can you post Vehicle class?

Comment: @Nemanja I shared the Vehicle Class. I guess the problem is not from the backend as I am able to post and get the data correctly from the Postman. Only from Client side I am not able to do so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spring Boot uses Jackson by default for serializing and deserializing request and response objects in your REST APIs.Since your setter method is named `setVIN(…)` Jackson assumes the variable is named **vIN** because of the Java naming conventions (variables should start with lower case letters). If you really want a capital letter use the `@JsonProperty` annotation on the setter or over field (or - for serialization - on the getter) like this:

```
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity
public class Vehicle {

    @Id
    private long id;
    private String make;
    private String model;
    private String variant;
    @JsonProperty("VIN")
    private int VIN;
    @JsonProperty("REG")
    private int REG;


    public Vehicle(long id, String make, String model, String variant, int VIN, int REG) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.make = make;
        this.model = model;
        this.variant = variant;
        this.VIN = VIN;
        this.REG = REG;
    }

    public Vehicle(){
        super();
    }

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getMake() {
        return make;
    }

    public void setMake(String make) {
        this.make = make;
    }

    public String getModel() {
        return model;
    }

    public void setModel(String model) {
        this.model = model;
    }

    public String getVariant() {
        return variant;
    }

    public void setVariant(String variant) {
        this.variant = variant;
    }

    public int getVIN() {
        return VIN;
    }

    public void setVIN(int VIN) {
        this.VIN = VIN;
    }

    public int getREG() {
        return REG;
    }

    public void setREG(int REG) {
        this.REG = REG;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Vehicle{" +
                "id=" + id +
                ", make='" + make + '\'' +
                ", model='" + model + '\'' +
                ", variant='" + variant + '\'' +
                ", VIN=" + VIN +
                ", REG=" + REG +
                '}';
    }
}
```

And on client side, you are sending field with name **maker**, but it should be **make** since that is the name of field in JAVA class.
So, change this line of client code:

```
  <Grid item xs ={12}  >
      <TextField required label="Maker" variant="outlined" placeholder="eg TATA" fullWidth id="maker" onChange={(e)=>{
          setVehicle({...vehicle, maker:e.target.value})
      }}/>
      </Grid>
```

To this :

```
<Grid item xs={12}>
                <TextField
                  required
                  label="Maker"
                  variant="outlined"
                  placeholder="eg TATA"
                  fullWidth
                  id="make"
                  onChange={(e) => {
                    setVehicle({ ...vehicle, make: e.target.value });
                  }}
                />
              </Grid>
```

And issue will be resolved.

Answer (score 0):

you need to check some fields in the class again.

```
maker -> make
REG -> reg
VIN -> vin
```

Comment: I checked it. But the behavior is from client side side only. As when I am doing a POST req from Postman, it is working fine and all the fields are getting the desired data.